# Keras - LSTM using Tensorflow Backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying this sample code from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) . Earlier I had problems using Keras - Theano on Windows now just migrated to Keras-Tensorflow on Ubuntu. The versions are Keras(2.0.2) and TF (0.12.1).

```
keras.__version__        # 2.0.2
tensorflow.__version__   # 0.12.1

import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 5000

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(nb_words=top_words)
# truncate and pad input sequences

max_review_length = 500

X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)
# create the model

embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=3, batch_size=64)
# Final evaluation of the model

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

The error is as follows and any help on solving the same would be highly appreciated

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework
  /tensor_util.py", line 302, in _AssertCompatible
  (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))


**TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.**
```

Comment: Try upgrading TF to latest version 1.0.x :)

Comment: Did you succeed to run anything using Tensorflow? Or is it the first time your'e trying to run something since you moved from Theano?

Comment: @LiorMagen I am able to work on tensorflow independently.

Comment: @NassimBen I just downgraded my Keras to 1.1.0 and the above code only works smoothly but other models now throw an error will try upgrading or downgrading TF.

Comment: Upgrade TF it should run smoothly, keras 2.0 is for TF 1.0 :)

Comment: Plz let us know how you solve this

Comment: I was able to resolve by upgrading to the latest tensorflow version. I used Tensorflow -1.0.1 and Keras - 2.0.2. It also worked when I used Keras - 1.1.0 and Theano backend - v 0.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine on newer version of Tensorflow ( I checked it on Tensorflow 1.0 and Keras 2.0.2). You are using an old version of Tensorflow. Please update you Tensorflow and it should work perfectly. The current available version of Tensorflow is 1.1